# Visibility issue of JInternalFrame

Tags: java, swing, visibility, jinternalframe, jdesktoppane

I am having one Application form.

I designed it using JAVA SWING.

I used many SWING Components like MenuBar,JPanel,JDesktopPane,JInternalFrame and many more.

On the Click event of one JButton i launched JInternalFrame inside the JDesktopPane.

But Whenever I Click on JInternalFrame the frame becomes invisible or only some part of the frame is available.

Here i share some snap i hope it will be helpful.

Can anyone tell me why it happens?And how to solve this bug?
[image]

Here the JInternalFrame is Completely visible.
[image]

Here When i Clicked on the calendar component some parts become invisible and only some parts of the frame is visible.

Some times the whole frame goes invisible.

How can i Solve this issue?

---

**EDIT:-**

After Solving  visibility problem how make JDesktopPane Transparent?
[image]

Comment: standard issue when Swing lightweight JComponents are overlay by AWT heavyweight Components,   JAVA SWING. could be Java Swing

Comment: @mKorbel Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @google for better help sooner post an SSCCE? short, runnable, compilable, caused a.m. issue

Comment: `JInternalFrame` is meant to be used in a `JDesktopPane`.

Comment: @trashgod i am running JInternal frame inside JDesktopPane. I made JDesktopPane opaque.

Comment: Finally removed one component that was not needed and finally solved this issue.Now one more thing i made JDesktopPane and loaded the JInternalFrame that works correctly. Now i used Nimbus theme and when i run these form i am having one Label behind of JDesktopPane which is not perfectly visible. I mean to say its color is changed. How can i make JDesktopPane transparent so the background is clearly visible? I also tried isOpaque().